# MS Visual Studio 2017 Visual C++: C4199 двухэтапный поиск имен не поддерживается для C++/CLI, C++/CX или OpenMP

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

Я нашел на сайте doc.microsoft.com, что данная ошибка решается через установку /Zc:twoPhase- в ОК. Хочу уточнить, это нужно в командную строку прописать  /Zc:twoPhase-OK ? Или же в свойствах проекта где-то нужно установить? Могу приаттачить проект целиком.

Answer (score 1):

В самом низу страницы, где Вы прочитали об этом, написано, как это сделать (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase?view=vs-2017)

- Открыть project's Property Pages диалог.
- Выбрать Configration Properties > C/C++ > Command Line property.
- Изменить Additional Options property добавив туда /Zc:twoPhase- и нажать OK.

Comment: Я так и пробовал, не помогло.

Comment: Кстати, тип проекта Visual C++ -> CLR -> Пустой проект CLR

Comment: Вот с этого и нужно начинать.

Comment: Как тогда можно построить такой проект?

Comment: а можете заменить на нормальный тип проекта? если да - проблема решена. Если нет, то кто мешает попробовать задать этот параметр и посмотреть, что будет.

Comment: Параметр задавал, не помогло.

Comment: помогло, спасибо! всё работает пока что